# Registration of ITagHelperActivator at Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector, tag-helpers

I want to resolve some dependencies at a `TagHelper` and I have read [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/247) that I must register the `ITagHelperActivator` interface.

I tried that with the following code:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITagHelperActivator>(new SimpleInjectorTagHelperActivator(container))
```

But I get the following error:

> ActivationException: The constructor of type UrlResolutionTagHelper
>   contains the parameter with name 'urlHelperFactory' and type
>   IUrlHelperFactory that is not registered. Please ensure
>   IUrlHelperFactory is registered, or change the constructor of
>   UrlResolutionTagHelper.

When I register `IUrlHelperFactory` with `UrlHelperFactory` then an other dependency is missing and I get an error for that too.

I guess I am doing something wrong, I don't want to register the complete framework.

Comment: Did you try to add services.AddMvc in ConfigureServices method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. By replacing the default tag helper activator, you redirected the resolution of *all* tag helpers to Simple Injector, but there are built-in tag helpers and they require the built-in container to be resolved.

Instead, v3.3 of the [SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc) NuGet package allows you to register a custom tag helper activator using the `AddSimpleInjectorTagHelperActivation` extension method as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSimpleInjectorTagHelperActivation(container);
    // rest of your configuration
}
```

The extension method takes care of the filtering of tag helpers. When a requested tag helper is located in an assembly starting with "Microsoft", the request for the tag helper is forwarded to the built-in tag helper activator. Otherwise the supplied `container` is requested to create the type.

You can override this default behavior by supplying a custom predicate to the `AddSimpleInjectorTagHelperActivation` method:

```
services.AddSimpleInjectorTagHelperActivation(container,
    type => type.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApplication"));
```

Applying the predicate becomes required when you start using 3rd party libraries that plug-in their own tag helpers. In that case the default filter for tags in the "Microsoft" namespace will fail.

Alternatively you can also use the `SimpleInjectorTagHelperActivator` directly, but note that this is more complicated to register correctly. You should typically use the `AddSimpleInjectorTagHelperActivation` extension method instead:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITagHelperActivator>(p =>
    new SimpleInjectorTagHelperActivator(
        container,
        type => type.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApplication"),
        new DefaultTagHelperActivator(p.GetService<ITypeActivatorCache>())));
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this tomorrow. It's not straight forward with two DI frameworks in the same project. Is this SimpleInjector's problem or every DI has the same problems?

Comment: This is absolutely no Simple Injector problem. You see this with all containers and we never had these problems before with the old ASP.NET platform. This is caused by a design flaw in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis: We pushed an improved version of our integration library I and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, it's much simpler now